# Django model form is_valid() in specific database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have two different database connections defined in my `settings.py` ('default' and 'banco1').

Then in some view I receive a POST containing some data that I want to validate against a `ModelForm` that I create:

```
 product_form = ProductForm(request.POST)
 if product_form.is_valid():
```

The product model:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=125, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('inventory.Category',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    metric = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
```

The Form:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'abbreviation', 'category', 'metric']
```

The view:

```
 def create(request):
        if request.method != 'POST':
            return JsonResponse('Operação inválida', safe=False)

        product_form = ProductForm(request.POST)
        if product_form.is_valid():
            f = product_form.save(commit = False)
            f.save(using=request.session['database'])
            return HttpResponse("Novo product salvo com sucesso")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Impossível salvar product. Verifique os campos")
```

The Product model is suposed to be saved always in the 'banco1' database, so the FK validations should be queried from the 'banco1' database, but whenever I try to validade with `product_form.is_valid()` Django tries to query the 'default' database and throws a validation error as the FK constraint can't be satisfied in the 'default' database.

How can I set a model form to make his validations agains a manually selected database?

**EDIT**

Was suggested to me to utilize a DB ROUTER schema to being able to select the proper database config, which works fine. My problem is that this selection should be made based in some criteria that not just the model. How can I pass some variables from the view to the `db_for_read` method in my db router class?

**EDIT2**

New ProductForm Class

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'abbreviation', 'category', 'metric']

    def __init__(self,database):
        category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.using(database).all())
```

trying to instantiate the form inside my view like this:

```
product_form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.session['database'])
```

Which gives me an error:

> **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I know that something is not valid with my manner to override the `__init__` method but i'm to noobish in python to realize that.

**EDIT 3**

Last errors:

> Traceback:
>
> File "C:\Users\Pavarine\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\gims\gims\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in get_response
>     149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\Users\Pavarine\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\gims\gims\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in get_response
>     147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Pavarine\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\gims\gims\gims\apps\inventory\views.py" in create
>     247.         if product_form.is_valid():
>
> File "C:\Users\Pavarine\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\gims\gims\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py"
>   in is_valid
>     161.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors
>
> File "C:\Users\Pavarine\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\gims\gims\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py"
>   in errors
>     153.             self.full_clean()
>
> File "C:\Users\Pavarine\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\gims\gims\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py"
>   in full_clean
>     362.         self._clean_fields()
>
> File "C:\Users\Pavarine\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\gims\gims\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py"
>   in _clean_fields
>     374.                 value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files,
>   self.add_prefix(name))
>
> File "C:\Users\Pavarine\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\gims\gims\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py"
>   in value_from_datadict
>     231.         return data.get(name)
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /inventory/product/create Exception
>   Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Do you have a [DB router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) setup telling it to use `banco1` as the `db_for_read` for `Product` models?

Comment: @mragh I can do this , but now I have another related question that comes in mind. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Please show the complete form and view.

Comment: @Alasdair I've updated the question

Comment: I've added a comment to @Nikita's answer because it's very similar to what I was going to suggest.

Comment: @Pavarine, see update in my answer to your edit2.

Comment: @Nikita I tried your changes and now I getting this error: " 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get' . Sorry for bothering you, I dont want to be lazy, i'm trying with my best efforts with trial and error. After this I'll clearly deep into Python OO concepts..but at time i can't do this by myself..

Comment: @Pavarine, whenever you get an error and ask about it, please, provide the stacktrace with the error as it allows to identify possible cause and solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry for this...question updated..

Comment: Have you updated `create` in `view.py`: from `product_form = ProductForm(request.POST)` to product_form = ProductForm(request.POST, db_to_use=request.session['database']). If yes, then show the `forms.py`. The error basicly says, that some field's widget can't use `get` method on `data`, because `data` is a tuple, while it should be dictionary to have the `get` method.

Comment: I did updated the create in view.py, but was getting the same errors. By trial and error I think i got it, calling the super like this: `ModelForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` and using the @Alasdair code to update the queryset of the fk like this: `self.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.using(database).all()` . If you wish you can update your answer with this, but I'll accept it anyway. Really thanks to you for the time you waste with me. Really apreciated that.

Comment: The `super` part shouldn't be an issue if it's used everywhere consistently.   @Alasdair's code might affect the error, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: My line that changes `self.fields` shouldn't cause any errors. I would usually do `def __init__(self, db_to_use, *args, **kwargs):`, and call `super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`. Then in the view, instantiate the form with `product_form = ProductForm(request.session['database'], request.POST)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable the router just add it to `DATABASE_ROUTERS` in your `setting.py`, see detailes here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers

Every router method gets `hints` dictionary, which should contain `instance` key representing the model instance being used. Depending on what information you want to get from the view, you might be good with the information from instance attributes. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#topics-db-multi-db-hints.

I.e.:

```
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    model_instance = hints.get('instance')   
    if model_instance is not None:
        pass
        #perform actions with model_instance attributes
    return None
```

Other then this I don't think there's other straight way to pass information from the active view to the router, as routers are supposed to work with models and make decisions based on models being used.

DB routers are used for automatic DB selection in models layer, but model methods allow to select the DB manually. See examples here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database

So the other solution is to redefine methods of your form class, i.e. `save()` (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method), and save the form data manually specifying the DB to use with `using` argument. I.e.:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        ...

    def save(self, commit=True):
        product_to_save=super(ProductForm, self).save(commit=False)
        #the above creates product_to_save instance, but doesn't saves it to DB
        product_to_save.save(using=='banco1')
        return product_to_save
```

In the comments I suggested to subclass the field that needs to be validated against the other DB, but there's probably even easier way... Since it's FK field it's probably the instance of `ModelChoiceField` which accepts the `queryset` argument in constructor, so you could provide it, i.e.:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
   category_field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.using('banco1'))
    ...
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships

**Answer to EDIT2**

The way you redefined the constructor your `database` argument gets `request.POST` and `request.session['database']` is not mapped to anything, that's why you get the error.

You should account for other arguments and also call superclass constructor or you'll break the MRO, so something like this should do the job:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, db_to_use='default', **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.using(db_to_use).all())
        #the below line suggested as improvement by Alasdair and confirmed as working by Pavarine, so I updated the answer here
        self.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.using(database).all()
```

and then as usual, but use named argument:

```
product_form = ProductForm(request.POST, db_to_use=request.session['database'])
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. It is possible to read SESSION data (previously saved inside view ) in the db_for_read method?

Comment: Session data is part of the active `request` in view layer and the DB router works on models layer. I don't know any straight way to do that, probably with hacking Djnago internals and using inner methods this could be achieved. Added one more idea in the answer.

Comment: The "manual selection" via the 'using' method works nice, and I'm alredy using it. But it just works when my model in question dont have any fk constraints, so the form.is_valid() passes the test and then I'm able to save "using" the db I want. If the model has fk constraints, the form.is_valid() fails the test before I have a chance to instruct him to validate against some other db I want, and not the default db. If I couldn't get any other anserws I'll be accepting yours, cause your directions are right. Thanks

Comment: @Pavarine, Oh, right. Then you need to subclass the fk *form-field* and redefine its `validate` method, where you'll perform custom validation using the DB you desire.

Comment: @Pavarine, see answer update, hope it'll solve your issue.

Comment: If you need to change the database dynamically, then you can override the form's `__init__` method and change `self.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.using(database)`

Comment: @Alasdair and Nikita  You guys rocks! I'm almost there! Using the **category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.using('banco1').all())** inside my ProductForm(ModelForm) class can validate and save this right. But I need that the 'banco1' database config to be dynamic, so I can pass this string when I create the FormModel, like: **product_form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.session['database'])** . I'm newbie in python as in django, so a tried to override the __init__ method from my ProductForm but I think its conflicting with the parent class (ModelForm) .. can u help me?

Comment: @Pavarine, add your code with new `__init__` and it's usage, and an error you get to your question to understand what's not working.

Comment: You're missing stars from your `super()` call. It should be `*args, **kwargs`.

Comment: @Alasdair, right, I rushed and forgot to unpack them, thank you!